# Finding example of a function having the required property.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

Does there exist any continuous function $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ which is not differentiable only at the integers and is not uniformly continuous everywhere?

The only function which I can think of is the periodic extension of the modulus function on $[-1,1]$ or something similar to that which are uniformly continuous everywhere. Hence they don't suit my purpose. Can anybody help me in finding out an example which satisfies the above condition?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not uniformly continuous everywhere"?  Do you simply mean that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yeah @Brian Moehring you have correctly guessed. By the phrase "not uniformly continuous everywhere" I mean to say that the function shouldn't be uniformly continuous on the whole of the real line $\Bbb R.$ Thanks for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be any function which is differentiable at $x$ iff $x$ is not an integer. [There are many such functions and you can build one using $|x|$]. If $f$ is not uniformly continuous we are done. If it is uniformly continuous then $f(x)+x^{2}$ satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For one example, define $f(n) = n^2$ for each integer $n$ and then $f(x)$ is linear on $n \leq x \leq n+1.$  In one line, this can be written as 
$$ f(x) = [x]^2(1-\{x\}) + (1+[x])^2\{x\}$$
where $[x]$ is the floor and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part.

Comment: How can I show that the function is not uniformly continuous everywhere?

Comment: The slope of the linear piece on $n \leq x \leq n+1$ is $2n+1,$ which is unbounded.